# how to set language to meet web accessibiity guideline?

Tags: html, lang

I'm checking my site for Web Accessibiity using the Web Accessibility Access Tool *WAVE) at http://wave.webaim.org

It tells me I should have a language specification, e.g.

```
<html lang="en">
```

Fair enough.  How can I do this in rails?

Currently in `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` I have

```
%head
  %title="#{controller.controller_name.capitalize} - #{controller.action_name}"
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
  = javascript_include_tag "application"
  = csrf_meta_tag
%body
  ...
```

and that generates:

```
<document>
<html>
<head>
  ...
<body>
...
```

but how would I get `lang="en"` into the `html` tag as recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one answer is to just put it in the body tag, i.e.

```
%body{lang:'en'}
```

which generates

```
<body lang="en">
```

However the WAVE tool still complains.